# Order of magnitude of a variable.

Tags: terminology, approximation, estimation

What will be the order of magnitude of a variable whose value varies between 0 and 1? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Order of magnitude usually refers to a factor of $10$, so over most of the interval the order of magnitude is $0.1$ or $1$, but if it is close to zero, the order of magnitude could be $10^{-20}$, for example.