# Definition of order of magnitude for a number

Tags: soft-question, definition

I was curious whether a clear-cut definition of order of magnitude for a number exists.

I have seen several posts in this forum touching upon, or tapping from, the concept of order of magnitude. None seemed (to me) to address the definition, though; for example 
[Order of Magnitude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370728/order-of-magnitude),
[What does "within the same order of magnitude" convey?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612670/what-does-within-the-same-order-of-magnitude-convey),
[Order of magnitude of a variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501401/order-of-magnitude-of-a-variable).

The ideal answer should assist the naive user in discriminating whether 50.1, or 99, should be of order 10 rather than order 100, for example. Or, at least, show why a clear-cut answer does not exist.

Comment: An "order of magnitude" is usually used in the case of a very large number. In this case, a number "close" to the given number is determined. I do not think that there is a definition covering all cases because the approximation is usually chosen depending on how large the given number is.

Comment: google gives :

or·der of mag·ni·tude
noun
noun: order of magnitude; plural noun: orders of magnitude
a class in a system of classification determined by size, each class being a number of times (usually ten) greater or smaller than the one before.
"values might be compared by order of magnitude, a staple in making ballpark estimates"
relative size, quantity, quality, etc.
"the new problems were of a different order of magnitude"
the arrangement of a number of items determined by their relative size.
"the items are arranged in ascending order of magnitude"

Comment: A bit of cross-pollination with discussions in the Physics forum: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/confront-order-of-magnitudes, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107088/order-of-magnitude,